# PHP MYSQL JOIN QUERY 2 Databases, Where table1.id = table2.id, How to display table2.content as table1.id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to put together a script that allows me to display links dynamically on my site.

I have 2 tables.  The first one, `domains` can have two values per row. These being, `domId` and `domain`.  The next table, `links` can contain a few values per row, the ones im working with here are `domId`(matches the domId of the `domains` table) `desc` and `link'.

Here is my query so far:

```
$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT `link`,`desc`,`domId` 
                 FROM `links` 
                WHERE `catId`="'.$pageCat.'" 
                   && (`modId`="1" || modId="'.$pageModel.'") 
             ORDER BY `domainId` ASC 
                LIMIT ' . $from . ', ' . $max_results2;
```

Here is the code that im using to display the info i need:

```
$linkLoop2 = '';
$linkAd = $row['link'];
$linkDesc = stripslashes($row['desc']);
$linkDomain = stripslashes($row['id']);
$linkLoop = '<ul class="bymodel-dllinks">';
$linkLoop2 .= '<li><a href="'.$linkAd.'" target="_tab">'.$linkDesc.' '.$linkDomain.'</a></li>';
$linkLoop3 = '</ul>';
```

What I am trying to do is find a way so that when $linkDomain is echo'd it will display the text i have stored in the `domain` field on the `domains` table.  Currently when `$linkDomain` is echo'd, it will display 303, which is the `domId` of the site i will be linking to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Join to select domain name from domainstable :

```
$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT l.link,l.desc,l.domId,d.domain
             FROM links l LEFT JOIN domains d ON d.domid = l.domid
            WHERE l.catId="'.$pageCat.'" 
               && (l.modId="1" || l.modId="'.$pageModel.'") 
         ORDER BY l.domainId ASC 
            LIMIT ' . $from . ', ' . $max_results2;
```

Comment: $linkQuery2 = 'SELECT l.link , l.desc , l.domId , d.domain FROM links l LEFT JOIN domains d ON d.domId = l.domId WHERE l.catId="'.$pageCat.'" && (l.modId="1" || l.modId="'.$pageModel.'") ORDER BY d.domain ASC LIMIT ' . $from . ', ' . $max_results2.'
              '; Thank you my friend, I owe you the hair i have left on my head :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `domain` column to your select statement.

```
$linkQuery2 = 'SELECT `link`,`desc`,`domId`,`domain`
             FROM `links` 
            WHERE `catId`="'.$pageCat.'" 
               && (`modId`="1" || modId="'.$pageModel.'") 
         ORDER BY `domainId` ASC 
            LIMIT ' . $from . ', ' . $max_results2;
```

Change `$linkDomain` to

```
$linkDomain = stripslashes($row['domain']);
```

Comment: Mior - The domain column is stored in another table on the same database, `domains` I did it this was so that there will be less room for error, I will only need to enter the domain name once.  Here is the error i get when applying those changes `Unknown column 'domain' in 'field list'` this is because `domain` is not a column in the `links` table?

Comment: My apologies. I didn't notice you hadn't already joined with this table. See Hamid's answer below :)

Comment: Thank you in anycase, Its now working perfectly! I am so excited :) The change in $linkDomain did definately help!